# $I(n)=∫_1^n(1+2^{-[x] })^x dx $ Prove: $n-1<I(n)<n+1,nϵN,n>1$

Tags: calculus, inequality

Let 
$ I(n)=∫_1^n(1+2^{-[x] })^x dx $ Prove: $n-1<I(n)<n+1,nϵN,n>1$.

> > To solve this problem I broke the iintegral and find each integral,looking for q better solu

Comment: Ok, so you "broke" the integral...and then?

Comment: found each ntegral

Comment: Please do complete correctly the question. And each integral seems to be pretty easy to calculate, yet the whole solution summed over $\;k=1,2,...,n-1\;$ seems to be rather hard to evaluate.

Comment: @Zacky $$\int_k^{k+1}\left(1+2^{-\lfloor x\rfloor}\right)^x\,dx=\int_k^{k+1}\left(1+2^{-k}\right)^x\,dx=\frac{\left(1+2^{-k}\right)^k\,2^{-k}}{\log(1+2^{-k})}$$

Comment: @Zacky Nop, I am not...but mathematically I can't see what else could he have done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\d}[1]{\text{ d}#1}$
Before I present my solutions, I would first highlight that your inequality on the left is false for $n = 2$, as:
$$
I(2) = \int_1^2 (1 + 2^{-\lfloor{x}\rfloor})^x \d{x} = \int_1^2 \left(1 + \frac{1}{2}\right)^x \d{x} \approx 1.84973 < 2
$$
However, it is true that $n - 1 < I(n) < n + 1$.

---

This is probably what you've done so far:
$$
I(n) = \int_1^n (1 + 2^{-\lfloor{x}\rfloor})^x \d{x} = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \int_{k}^{k+1} (1 + 2^{-\lfloor{x}\rfloor})^x \d{x} = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\int_{k}^{k+1} (1 + 2^{-k})^x \d{x}
$$
Observe that for any $a > 1$, $a^x$ is strictly convex. For any convex function $f : [c,d] \to \mathbb{R}$,  we have $f$ lying below the line joining $(c, f(c))$ and $(d, f(d))$. This means that the area under $f$ is $\leq$ the area of the trapezium with the vertices $(c,0)$, $(c, f(c))$, $(d, f(d))$ and $(d,0)$. Thus:
\begin{align*}
\int_{k}^{k+1} (1 + 2^{-k})^x \d{x} &< \frac{1}{2}((1+2^{-k})^k + (1+2^{-k})^{k+1}) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}(1+2^{-k})(2 + 2^{-k}) \\
&= 1 + 2^{-k} + 2^{-k-1} + 2^{-2k-1}
\end{align*}
Therefore:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\int_{k}^{k+1} (1 + 2^{-k})^x \d{x} &< \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(1 + 2^{-k} + 2^{-k-1} + 2^{-2k-1}) \\
&= n - \frac{4^{1-n}}{3} - 3(2^{-n}) + \frac{5}{6} \\
&< n + 1
\end{align*}
To show that $I(n) > n - 1$, simply observe that $(1 + 2^{-k})^x > 1$ for all $k \geq 1$, so:
$$
I(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\int_{k}^{k+1} (1 + 2^{-k})^x \d{x} > \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\int_{k}^{k+1} 1 \d{x} = n - 1 
$$

Answer (score -1):

Split your I tegral up between when floor(x) changes. So we get sum_k=1 to n-1 of integral from k to k+1 (1+2^-k)^x dx.

The integral will be 1/ln(1+2^-k)*[(1+2^-k)^k+1 - (1+2^-k)^k] = 2^-k * (1+2^-k)^(k+1) /ln(1+2^-k).

I don't know how you can show that the sum of these integrals will be between n a d n+1, so I will stop here.